# How to include block of code to every page except base.html

Tags: python, django, forms, smarty

I need to create a small side block with form(it contains only one field and button) and I want it to be included to every page except `base.html`

I thought about making simple view function, but maybe there are better ways to do this?

I'm using Python and Django 1.6

Comment: You can use template inheritance in django, but your question is not specific enough for a specific answer. Do other templates inherit from base.html?

Comment: Yep, all templates inherit from base.html

Comment: So I need to place my block in base html so templates could inherit it but also i need to exclude it from start page

Comment: so to clarify, at least one of your views uses base.html directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you shouldn't use base.html directly, but because you are and because it would be a huge hassle to change it in every other template, what you can do is, in the view function that returns base.html, you can add a boolean to the context and check the boolean to determine what template you are using.

Something like this:

```
def view_that_uses_base.html(request):
   is_base = True
   return render_to_response("base.html", {"is_base":is_base}, RequestContext(request,{}))
```

And then in the template:

```
{% block sidebar %}
{% if is_base%}
{% else %}

#Your code here
{% endif %}
{% endblock sidebar %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use templates to do that. 
In other words, try creating **$DJANGO_ROOT/templates/main.html** using the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 {% block one_field_and_a_button %}
   <input />
   <button>I am everywhere</button>
 {% endblock %}
 {% block my_custom_content %}
 {% endblock %}
</body>
<html>
```

Then all other templates must extend that main.html template and insert their own data.
Imagine this is **$DJANGO_ROOT/templates/login.html.** It will only replace "my_custom_content" and will inherit all other blocks including "one_field_and_a_button"

```
{% extends 'templates/main.html' %}
{% block my_custom_content %} 
 Hello World! This is the login
{% endblock %}
```

Finally, if you want to have a base.html that does not have that part of the code containing one field and a button, you can do the following. 
Imagine this is **$DJANGO_ROOT/templates/base.html**. It will replace both "one_field_and_a_button" and "my_custom_content". However, in this case, "one_field_and_a_button" will be replaced with blank space that will not show in your html code.

```
{% extends 'templates/main.html' %}
{% block one_field_and_a_button %} {% endblock %}
{% block my_custom_content %} 
 Hello World! This is my base.html template
{% endblock %}
```

Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use block tag in base.html, i think you are searching foe something like this

base.html

```
{% block code %}
 {% include 'sidebar.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

index.html

```
{% extends base.html %}
{% block code %}
{% endblock %}
```

and every other templates
 just extend base html

```
{% extends base.html %}
```

Comment: He said he doesn't want it in base.html... This code will include it in base.html

Comment: every template will be extended from basr.html, he might be meant base.htm as home page, that's why i wrote the solution like this.

Comment: See my comment under the question itself: he might have meant several things, but question needs to be more specific.

Comment: Yes , i agree with you. And i didn' t see yor comment while replying. That's why mention in my answer that ,'you may be searching for something like this'